# The Script is a type which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to disable a certain script from a a gameObject but I got an error saying my script was a type and that it was not given in this context here is my script.

`GameObject.Find("Obstacle").GetComponent(PlayerMovement).enabled = false`

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle")){

            GameOverScreen.Setup(ScoreNum);
             GetComponent(PlayerMovemnt).enabled = false;
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*I already tryed to just so people dont tell me to do it*".. tried to what?....

Comment: It has been a while since I've messed with Unity but it seems you need to [do it this way](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: Try GameObject.Find("Obstacle").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false

Comment: As @Smaika pointed out. You typoed